# APNS push notification is delayed

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Our application uses APNS push notifications to notify our clients about some change on server or if there is any new message for the user. Many of our clients have complaint us that if they keep the app or phone idle for long time(that is, doesn't open our app for long time) and in the meanwhile if push notification is sent to them, they either don't receive them at all or receive them very late. The delay varies from an hour to couple of days sometimes. This is completely unacceptable to our clients. On my server logs, I found that push notification is pushed immediately from our server to APNS server. Now APNS makes the delay in sending the notification to apple devices. Once the device starts receiving the notifications, then subsequent messages are sent immediately. Can someone here please help us or guide us why APNS might be doing so. Does APNS mark any device or application as inactive if it is in idle mode for some time and then it checks at regular interval if app has become active? Is there a way to solve this issue from our end so that the push notification is sent immediately to the apple devices without any delay. The apple devices on which we are facing issues ranges from iPhone-6 to iPhone-X and iOS version from iOS-10.x to iOS-11.x. We have not checked this in older versions though as most of our clients have updated their devices to latest iOS versions.

Comment: APNS docs clearly says that APNS is not 100% reliable to ensure every push goes through and reaches all the devices. Its a best effort service, once APNS receives your packets, when it gets pushed to devices depends on number of factors up on which you have no control. So you should use APNS scarcely  and when necessary. You cant implement a chat app using APNS (Mentioning because u said about messages in your question) You can implement various workarounds to reduce the delay though. Opt for various background modes like background fetch, location updates

Comment: and when your app gets chance query your backend to get updates, try using silent notification in addition with normal APNS to inform new content available state (again it uses APNS so cant completely depend on it) etc etc

Comment: @Sandeep: Thanks for your reply, Sandeep, I am not using APNS for chatting. But the problem is suppose my application is in background and in the meantime, if someone sends me a message, I need to push it to client device. So that I can notify the client with badge. But sometimes the notifications gets misses. So is there a way I can overcome this issue?